# Proof for hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i^2$ =$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |a_i,_j|^2$ if A=[$a_i,_j$] is hermitian and $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues.

Been thinking about this question for a while but  I don't know where to start. I have had a linear algebra course but didn't do too well, its all very abstract for me. My biggest problem is that I do not know how to approach the questions.

Comment: You will give Readers an easier time parsing what you are asking about if you use the body of the Question to fully state the problem.  Stuffing it all into the title might make you feel the Question is "short and easy", but it does put a significant burden on those willing to help.

Comment: *Hint*: compute the eigenvalues of $A^*A$

Comment: @hardmath plus mathjax doesn't render in titles on the mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, consider the matrix $A^*A$. Let us calculate its trace:
$tr(A^*A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n ((A)_{i,j}(A^*)_{j,i}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} * \overline {a_{i,j}} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{i,j}|^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{i,j}|^2$

Since A is hermitian, we know that $A=A^*$ and therefore $A^*A=A^2$, so we get that $tr(A^2)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{i,j}|^2$

At last, we'll remember that the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, and the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are exactly $\{\lambda_i^2|1 \le i \le n \}$ (it is easy to be convinced so), and we get the desired identity:

$\sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{i,j}|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 = tr(A^2)$